# Entity Framework .Net core not adding stored procedure classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am generating Entity Framework classes in a .NET Core application using this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server name;Database=DB name;user id=user name;password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models/DB
```

It is working well and creating models for all the tables and views in the database. But strangely it's not creating models for stored procedures.

Is there anything I am missing in scaffold syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework Core creates entity classes only for tables; stored procedures or views are still not supported.

But there is a Github issue tracking on it that you can find more info: [Stored procedure mapping support](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/245)

How to add stored procedures (like a normal entity) after scaffolding:

1. Create the output model of your stored procedure:

   ```
   public class SampleModel
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Add a new `DbSet` to your context :

   ```
   public virtual DbSet<SampleModel> SampleModels { get; set; }
   ```
3. Use your model for the output:

   ```
   var sampleModels = _context.SampleModels.FromSql($"EXEC ReturnAllSampleModels").ToList();
   ```

Done.

Comment: thanks for your response. When I scaffold, it generated tables and Views models. Only storedprocs are not included.
It seems like they have extended support for views but sps are still missing.

Comment: @urvishmandaliya; you can add sp's to your model as a said. please mark answered as an accepted if it helps.

Comment: thanks for your helped. It worked. I am able to call the SP now. But the issue I am facing with parameters that I am passing params but everytime generating 0 results set.